# `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`

Tags: python, typeerror

My programs runs, but after I enter my answers I keep getting an error that says

> "TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

```
def calculateCaloriesFromFat(fatGrams):
    caloriesFromFat = fatGrams * 9
    return caloriesFromFat


def calculateCaloriesFromCarbs(carbGrams):
    caloriesFromCarbs = carbGrams * 4
    return caloriesFromCarbs
  

def main():
    userFatGrams = float(input("How many Fat Grams?"))
    userCarbGrams = float(input("How many Carb Grams?"))

    caloriesFromFat = calculateCaloriesFromFat(userFatGrams)
    caloriesFromCarbs = calculateCaloriesFromCarbs(userCarbGrams)

    print("calories from fat", + format(caloriesFromFat, "f"),
          "calories from carbs", + format(caloriesFromCarbs, "f"))


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
def calculateCaloriesFromFat(fatGrams):
    caloriesFromFat = fatGrams * 9
    return caloriesFromFat


def calculateCaloriesFromCarbs(carbGrams):
    caloriesFromCarbs = carbGrams * 4
    return caloriesFromCarbs

def main():
    userFatGrams = float(input("How many Fat Grams?"))
    userCarbGrams = float(input("How many Carb Grams?"))

    caloriesFromFat = calculateCaloriesFromFat(userFatGrams)
    caloriesFromCarbs = calculateCaloriesFromCarbs(userCarbGrams)

    print("calories from fat " + format(caloriesFromFat, "f") + "calories from carbs " + format(caloriesFromCarbs, "f"))

main()
```

However, consider changing `format(caloriesFromFat, "f")` to:

```
print("calories from fat " + str(caloriesFromFat) + " calories from carbs " + str(caloriesFromCarbs))
```

By doing so you'll eliminate any extra zeros you don't need.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `+` signs here:

```
print("calories from fat", format(caloriesFromFat, "f"),
      "calories from carbs", format(caloriesFromCarbs, "f"))
```